# I have root folder, in root folder i placed .css file, now i want to use this css file in my project with relative path

Tags: javafx-8

I have root folder, in root folder i placed .css file, now i want to use this css file in my project with relative path in javaFX application.

Please help in this regard.
Thank you

Comment: You need to show us the structure of the project for us to help.

Comment: not sure where the file is but you can use /../ to go "up" a level.

Comment: i have two Project one is component and other one is cotainer(main application), in Container i have Option to press f1 for help file , but we Need to provide help file with component jar file. css, JS fies are already in Container Project only reference is i am using in component, when i put our component jar file in application root Folder and press f1 it is not uses css and js file. please suggest.

Comment: Structure of Project is C:\Users\mandalr\Desktop\project name \appData\help\css, js, html file and images

Comment: Question is how to use root data forlder css and js file for component help html file ?